# css misunderstanding with "position:fixed"

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem where the top div is about 20px from the top of the viewport when it should be at the top:

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
</div>
<div id="bottom">
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #00c;
    position: fixed;
}
```

If I remove `position: fixed` from `#top`, the result is as expected, the `#top` div is right against the top.

How can I make the `#top` div against the top of the viewport, if `#top` has `position:fixed`?

P.S. (I can't make demo on http://jsfiddle.net, because the problem is not visible there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was really hard to understand, but I think you want the position to be fixed and the div to touch the top?

Add `top: 0px;` to `#top`.

Comment: I believe even `top: 0;` would be sufficient.

Comment: There might also be an inherited border, padding or margin.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem isn't visible in jsfiddle, that means there must be a difference between your HTML code and theirs.

Use a tool like Firebug or "Inspect Element" to see all the active CSS styles that are applied to `#top` (and any parent elements) until you find a difference.